# I'd like to ask a question about facebook group moderation

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question about facebook group moderation concerns regarding minors. I'm concerned about where to draw the line for due diligence responsibility protecting minors in my moderator/administration policy.

But there's no facebook tag nor one for minors. And so I'm wondering if the question would fit here.

I read this: [Do we need separate tags for different sites?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/do-we-need-separate-tags-for-different-sites/19#19). It seems a facebook tag together with a "minors" or "underage" tag defines the context of a social site (facebook) where there are strong impulse for open groups and the potential hazards this poses to site owners.

Comment: Seems my actual question was too "dumb". Oh well. I've since taken it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly on topic to ask here as it deals with moderation concerns.  There is a "children" tag and "minors" should probably be added as a synonym.  Also, do keep in mind the site is still in VERY early public beta, so a lot of tags aren't going to exist yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `social-networks`-tag would be fine to abstract from the certain social network, because the issue could also happen at myspace. i assume that the terms for questionable content are nearly identical on all those platforms

Comment: Its not a matter of questionable content. Its a matter of a public forum where children have access and where the parent site's profile would promote open forum (not closed, thus eliminating the hazard). I also see it as an issue of the site specific policies and safeguards facebook affords.